# ProcessBuilder("command","-v","date").start() fails with IOException: No such file or directory

Tags: java, shell, kotlin, processbuilder

I am trying to find out whether a command exists (eg. `date`) using the `command` shell builtin, on Ubuntu. However the following (scroll further below for java snippet)

```kotlin
//main.kt
fun main(){
      val proc=ProcessBuilder("command","-v","date").start() //line 37
}
```

fails to run with stack trace

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "command": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:37)
    at MainKt.main(main.kt)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 3 more
```

`command` is definitely available on my bash -

```bash
user@pc:~$ type command
command is a shell builtin
```

**Why does the error occur?**

Note that most other similar queries (there are plenty on SO) got solved via syntactic corrections or bad file paths, and don't apply here.

**Env:**
JDK 17 on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

**Java code**:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
//rough.java
public class rough {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ProcessBuilder("command","-v","date").start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass the command to `bash` if it's only available there.

Comment: @f1sh it's available in sh too. What does ProcessBuilder usually launch the command in?

Comment: in no shell at all. That's why all of the shell's features are not available.

Comment: @f1sh can confirm; does work ("bash -c command -v date".split(" ")). But then why do commands like ("echo","a")  and ("date") work out of the box, without having to pass a shell?

Comment: lineage: `date` is a _program_ (binary/executable file) which ProcessBuilder can exec. `echo` is a builtin in most shells but is _also_ a program, as `type -a echo` will show you, so exec-ing it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sentence already has the solution:

> […] using the `command` *shell builtin* […]

`ProcessBuilder` execs processes directly and does not invoke a shell. And since a shell-builtin is a functionality provided by the shell and not a binary, it cannot be invoked (directly) with `ProcessBuilder`.

If you want to run a shell, you need to do so explicitly:

```
new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "command -v date").start();
```